# id <ProtocolDelegate> in brackets: why not typedef?

Tags: protocols, typedef, delegation

I have found a tiny variant of the usual delegation pattern:

My protocol is defined in some Protocol.h, i.e,

```
@protocol ProtocolDelegate <NSObject>
//…
@end

//The variant, see below
typedef NSObject <ProtocolDelegate> Delegate;
```

Next, in my ViewController.h

```
@interface: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong)  Delegate*delegateOfviewController;
//…
@end
```

Then, in my ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize delegateOfviewController;
//…
@end
```

Finally, in my AppDelegate.m

```
//…
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//…
self.ViewController.delegateOfviewController = self;
//…
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
}
```

And everything goes perfectly well. Is it really equivalent to the usual way " id  delegate", or do you think that such a typedef should be avoided?

Thanks!

jgapc

Answer (score 0):

The only difference should be whether or not you use a pointer symbol. I do not believe there is any difference, but why make a typedef when Objective-C gives you id?